# Manually set value Member of Combobox

Tags: c#

Actually I need to set the value member of combobox using Foreach loop

My code goes like this.

```
foreach(DataRow row in dsTable.Tables["mytable"].Rows)
{
    combobox1.Items.Add(row["my column"]);
}
```

how do i set value member on it?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you want to achieve here. Which 'value' member are you trying to set? And to what?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the definition and some examples of combobox use.

[msdn combobox link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx#Y13783)

Basically a combobox accepts "objects" so u could add any kind of items in it.
Hopes it helps.

Comment: You can add objects this part is very much true, but this doesn't help the problem OP is facing ,solution by @digEmall is how to go about for this

Answer (score 0):

You're not binding a `DataSource` so basically there's no point in setting the `ValueMember` property.

You should do this instead of the loop:

```
combobox1.DataSource = dsTable.Tables["mytable"];
combobox1.ValueMember = "MyValueColum";
combobox1.DisplayMember = "MyDisplayColumn";
```